# How to limit the amount of a string printed out (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, api

I have a question on how i can limit the amount of a string that is printed out in java.  For instance i want something like this:

Orignal String:

> "In the long history of the world,
>   only a few generations have been
>   granted the role of defending freedom
>   in its hour of maximum danger. I do
>   not shrink from this responsibility -
>   I welcome it. "

I want this:

> "In the long history of the world,
>   only a few generations have been
>   granted the role of defending freedom
>   in its hour of maximum..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a java.text.BreakIterator, something like this:

```
String s = "I want to truncate this";
int chars = 10;
BreakIterator b = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
b.setText(s);
int cutAt = bi.following(chars);
System.out.println(s.substring(0,cutAt))
```

Comment: Good one! Didn't know the BreakIterator!

Comment: Thank you! i knew how to do it the long inefficient way...I wanted to know if there was a built in way to do it. Thanks! I'll accept this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like:

```
if (s.length() > 25)
    System.out.println (s.substring (0,22) + "...");
else
    System.out.println (s);
```

This lets strings that are short enough print as they are, while shortening (with an ellipsis appended) those that are too long.

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourString = "very long string";
maxCharToPrint= 10;
System.out.println(yourString.substring(0, maxCharToPrint));
```

Comment: what if yourString.length() == 5?

Right, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range.`

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "your long sentence"
s.Substring(start, end);
```

in your case

```
s.Substring(0, max);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Apache Commons' [org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class, which provides the following utility methods:

```
String abbreviate(String str, int maxWidth)
String abbreviate(String str, int offset, int maxWidth)
String abbreviateMiddle(String str, String middle, int length)
```